# Need to get google maps markers in XML and another data based on the same parameters in HTML with one Ajax request

Tags: php, html, xml, ajax, google-maps

I've got a script taking user's current position, sending it to a php file via Ajax request which checks for nearby coordinates with a database and returns an xml-format markers which are then populated in google maps.
My problem is that I also need to get some tabulated data based on that ajax request which will not go in the google maps plugin. It will go on top of the map, like relevant data for the markers on the actual map. The problem is that I don't know how to create xml tables.

**What I really want to do is for my php script to produce some html-format tables which I then append to my html file, by the same ajax request which I have used for getting the xml  markers.**

PHP parsing file -

```
 <?php
include("config.php");

// Get parameters from URL
$center_lat = $_GET["lat"];
$center_lng = $_GET["lng"];
$radius = $_GET["radius"];

// Start XML file, create parent node
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);



// Search the rows in the markers table
$query = sprintf("SELECT address, name, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('".$center_lat."') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('".$center_lng."') ) + sin( radians('".$center_lat."') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM venues HAVING distance < '".$radius."' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
  mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $center_lat),
  mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $center_lng),
  mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $center_lat),
  mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $radius));
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
if (!$result) {
  die("Invalid query: " . mysqli_error($mysqli));
}


// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("name", $row['name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("distance", $row['distance']);

}

echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

And my Ajax request.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    var clientPosition ;
    $("#map_canvas").gmap().live("init", function(evt, map) {
        $("#map_canvas").gmap("getCurrentPosition", function(position, status) {
        if ( status === "OK" ) {
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var lng = position.coords.longitude;
            var currentPositionMarker = "<marker name=\'Your Position\'     lat="+lat+" lng="+lng+"/>";
            var clientPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            $("#map_canvas").gmap("addMarker", {"position": clientPosition, "bounds": \'true\'});
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url: "someurl.php",           
                dataType: "xml",
                data:{
                    lat:lat,
                    lng:lng,
                    radius:250
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    var markers = (data).getElementsByTagName("marker");
                    $(currentPositionMarker).appendTo(markers);
                    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                        var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
                        var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
                        var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
                        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
                        var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
                        bounds.extend(point);   
                        displayMarker(name,point);
                        map.fitBounds(bounds);
                    };
                }
            });
            function displayMarker(title, point) {
                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    title: title,

                    position: point
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(title);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            }
        }
        });
    });
});
```

I know this should be simple and I have looked through PHP documentation and found some relevant stuff, but when I implement it, for example $dom->loadHTML(); the ajax script stops working and does not even populate the new relevant markers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I was thinking to maybe get the information I need for the tables in the <marker> as attributes and after that take it with the client-side script (ajax request) and create a table from there, but I believe it's lots of code for nothing. What do you think?

Comment: check the response (firebug/developer-tools)->network, what do you see for someurl.php ?

Comment: I think that is the way to do it.  You can manipulate the page DOM (outside of the map) using javascript.

Comment: Well in firebug, when I add this 
    $dom->loadHTML("<html><body>Test<br></body></html>");
    echo $dom->saveHTML();
to the php parses, I get only the html, but not the xml anymore..